# How does Tor deal with IP changes on cellular data

Tags: configuration, android, torcheck

Example: When using cellular data it is common to lose connection, and reconnect. How does Tor Browser deal with this, are there any security implications? i.e leaking of data to connected websites?

Comment: I used Orbot in the past and when the connection gone down, It seemed that a type of "kill-switch" prevented the outgoing connections to be made through normal connection.